# Issues when trying to run Envoy front-proxy example

Tags: docker, envoyproxy

I'm new with all this technologies and environments.
I tried to run the lyft/envoy example that locate in the [github repository](https://github.com/lyft/envoy) .

I followed their [guide](https://lyft.github.io/envoy/docs/install/sandboxes/front_proxy.html) , step by step, and its not working.
I'm using Docker as container platform ( as mention in the guide), python version 2.7.13 installed.

When i execute 'docker-compose up --build -d' as mentioned in the guide, I suppose to see when i execute 'docker-compose ps' that the envoy-fronproxy and the other two services are UP and running, but in my case , the envoy-frontproxy is UP and the other two services failed with 'Exit 127'.[image]
Additionally, when I execute 'docker-compose up --build -d' I get somewhere in the middle of the output log the following error(maybe its relevant):
[image]
I'll just say I did not change any configuration or any file in the supplied example folder.

**Update 2/6/17:** 
I adding docker logs screen shots:[image][image][image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show us the output of: `docker-compose logs service1` and the same for service2

Comment: It's working nice for me. And I also have the red lines that you posted :(

Comment: Can you clone again? Then cd `examples/front-proxy`; `docker-compose up --build` ?

Comment: i did it again. and still, not working :( . which OS you are using? (i'm with win10) and i'm using the docker tool for windows. where did you clone the repository?(location). And maybe it's related to that I have proxy at work?

Comment: I'm using Mac. I've cloned this: https://github.com/lyft/envoy. The three containers are up. It's too odd that you don't have the start_service.sh script in the containers :/

Comment: Thank you, your last comment made me think about the solution. I will write down the full answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research and debugging, and with little help from @Robert , i managed to solve the issue.
The missing file `start_service.sh` was not found , because it was not UNIX EOL conversion .
Simple `dos2unix` solved the issue.

@Robert, thanks! and i hope it will save time for others.